# Expressionengine matrix ajax pagination

Tags: ajax, matrix, pagination, expressionengine, jquery-isotope

hey i had a PHP+mySQL+jQuery featured section that blocked by Isotope
and i worked just fine you can see here

> http://egyptianartsgroup.com/videos.php

i want to do it in EE matrix but im having a problem with ajax pagination

heres my code for outputting matrix rows to isotope

```
<div id="container" class="photos clearfix variable-sizes">
   {exp:channel:entries channel="featured" url_title="main-featured" limit="1"}
   {featured_items search:active="Yes" sort="asc" limit="5" offset="0"}
   {if type == "Video"}
      <div class="photo video">
         {thumb_image}
        <img src="{path}_thumbnails/{filename}.{extension}" />
        {/thumb_image}
        <a href="{vlink}" class="featuredVideoIcon" t = "video" title="{overlayed_title}"></a>
        <a href="{vlink}" class="FeaturedTitleLink" t = "video" title="{overlayed_title}"><h2 class="FeaturedTitle">{overlayed_title} -- {row_count} of / {total_rows}</h2></a>
        </div>
   {if:else}
   <div class="photo image">
            {thumb_image}
            <img src="{path}_thumbnails/{filename}.{extension}" />
            {/thumb_image}
            <a  class="featuredEnlargIcon" href= "{thumb_image}" title="{overlayed_title}" t = "image"></a>
            <a  class="FeaturedTitleLink" href= "{thumb_image}" t = "image" title="{overlayed_title}"><h2 class="FeaturedTitle">{overlayed_title} -- {row_count} of / {total_rows}</h2></a>
            </div>
   {/if}

   {/featured_items}

   {/exp:channel:entries}
</div>
```

any ideas to get the ajax pagination work ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to seperate your photos from Videos and paginate each using:

```
  {paginate}
  {pagination_links}
  {/paginate}
```

Source: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/pagination_page.html#pagination-links

As for Ajax you could use: https://github.com/reusserdesign/ExpressionEngine-Ajax-Pagination